# What are the ways to find a Non-Deterministic Finite Automata (NFA) that accepts complementary of the language accepted by a given NFA?

Tags: computer-science, theory, finite-automata, automata, automata-theory

The only way I know of find a NFA that accepts complementary of the language accepted by a given NFA, is to convert the NFA to an equivalent DFA and then make the non-final states as final state and final states as non-final. Is there any other way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, given an NFA `A`, it can be converted to an equivalent (in the sense of accepting the same language) DFA `B`, which in turn can be modified into `C` by making every terminal state non-terminal and vice versa in order to accept the complement of the language accepted by `A`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is your solution.

I feel there must be a way to prove that no other solution would exist. But I can not establish a proof right now.